How do I compare how Flutter and Native Android build and display frames?
I am trying to compare the time to build and show a frame in both Flutter and Android Native application but I'm not understanding correctly how to compare them. I know that in native applications, the UI Thread build the frame and the RenderThread displays it as soon as the UI finishes building it and it should finish both works in 16ms, and in Flutter the UI Thread and Raster Thread works in parallel and each has 16ms to finish...
I am using Macrobenchmark to obtain native metrics and flutter driver/integration_test.
FrameDurationCpuMs: P90 15.8ms (UI + Render)
"90th_percentile_frame_build_time_millis": 7.39 (UI)
"90th_percentile_frame_rasterizer_time_millis": 7.059 (Raster)
But checking those results, I'm not sure if I misunderstood something or is this case, Flutter is being better by far? Or to compare I should sum the build time and rasterizer time...
